# Tick mark display order

Tags: matlab, graphics

Is there any way in Matlab to specify that the tick marks should appear on top of the graph?

I'm making a plot with shading for when recessions occur. I currently plot a patch object as the farthest back object in a plot, but this obscures any tick marks that occur during this window. For example:

[image: recess]

Is there a way to get the tick marks to appear in front of this shading?

Comment: There probably is a way to (re-)draw your axes after the plot has been drawn, bringing the ticks to the front again. How I do not know, this is mainly a comment to inspire others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you first draw the patch then the bar plot, this is what a solution would look like:

```
h=gca;
h.Layer='top'
```

This uses the layer property of the axes to force the bar plot to be on top.

If you have an older matlab version you might want to add this instead:

```
set(gca,'Layer','top')
```